# Python, module Mathplotlib

Tags: python-3.x

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from math import sin
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 1000)
y = sin(x / 2) ** 2
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Error: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: How to fix it??

Comment: What is the quesion you would like to ask?